# Common java AMQP interface

Tags: jms, messaging, amqp, messagebroker

Hi is there any java shared common amqp interface that is shared among all the amqp implementors?

Something similar to JMS, in a way to avoid vendor locking for amqp message broker implementor.

Answer (score 0):

AMQP is a standardised Messaging protocol and JMS is an API. You can use a AMQP client library that implements the JMS API if you want but it is not necessary. All AMQP libraries should able to talk with an AMQP broker, if their AMQP version is compatible.

So the answer is: yes, you can use JMS.